# Обрезка строки после нахождение символов

Tags: php

Есть данные в виде json

```
[{ "mask": "+247-####", "cc": "AC", "name_en": "Ascension", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Остров Вознесения", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+376-###-###", "cc": "AD", "name_en": "Andorra", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Андорра", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+971-5#-###-####", "cc": "AE", "name_en": "United Arab Emirates", "desc_en": "mobile", "name_ru": "Объединенные Арабские Эмираты", "desc_ru": "мобильные" },
{ "mask": "+971-#-###-####", "cc": "AE", "name_en": "United Arab Emirates", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Объединенные Арабские Эмираты", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+93-##-###-####", "cc": "AF", "name_en": "Afghanistan", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Афганистан", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+1 (268) ###-####", "cc": "AG", "name_en": "Antigua & Barbuda", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Антигуа и Барбуда", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+1 (264) ###-####", "cc": "AI", "name_en": "Anguilla", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Ангилья", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+355 (###) ###-###", "cc": "AL", "name_en": "Albania", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Албания", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+374-##-###-###", "cc": "AM", "name_en": "Armenia", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Армения", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+599-###-####", "cc": "AN", "name_en": "Caribbean Netherlands", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Карибские Нидерланды", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+599-###-####", "cc": "AN", "name_en": "Netherlands Antilles", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Нидерландские Антильские острова", "desc_ru": "" },
{ "mask": "+599-9###-####", "cc": "AN", "name_en": "Netherlands Antilles", "desc_en": "Curacao", "name_ru": "Нидерландские Антильские острова", "desc_ru": "Кюрасао" },
{ "mask": "+244(###)###-###", "cc": "AO", "name_en": "Angola", "desc_en": "", "name_ru": "Ангола", "desc_ru": "" }]
```

Пробовал обрезать вот подобным способом:

```
foreach ($phonecodes as $item) {
   $country[] = strstr($item->mask, '(', true);;
}
```

Строки где отсутствует знак '(' возвращает пустые, что естественно не есть нормально. В общем задача из json получить коды страны и в дальнейшем коды городов которые заключены в скобки.

Comment: Для начала `json_decode` и работа с получившимися массивами, а потом регулярное выражение (тут я не мастер, но думаю здесь Вам помогут с ним)

Comment: Вообще с получением массива из json проблем нету, проблема лишь с форматированием строки :)

Comment: и зачем вы json привели, если с ним проблем нет? проблема в регулярках? вот и напишите тогда примеры входных строк с номерами и соответствующего результата.

Comment: Согласен с @teran потому что не ясно где код страны и код города в каждом из примеров. Вот регулярное выражение которое частично решает вашу задачу:   preg_match('{\D(\d{2,})\D}',$str,$pockets); Ответ в $pockets[1]

Comment: teran json я привел с целью показать как выглядит маска

Comment: @Alexus Есть страны где нету вообще кодов города, малое население и т.д. Из за того что может быть код страны быть 1-4 цифр, а код города может состоять из 2-7 цифр, а где то вообще отсутствовать. В общем для этого я привел пример json пакета.

Comment: вы нам привели просто набор текста с телефонами. объясните что конкретно здесь является кодом страны,а что города и так далее.

Comment: @teran "+247-#### здесь код страны 247 и отсутствует код города, +1 (264) ###-####" здесь код страны 1 и код города 264.  И в пояснение вроде все написал, в примере кода видно что парсю mask.

Comment: вы ровным счетом нигде не написали, что первые цифры это кода страны, а далее в скобках опционально город. Вообще нигде. То что вы "парсите" `mask` и ежу понятно. Вы написали, что код может отсутствовать, но не писали, что код - это цифры в скобках. Да, мы можем это и предположить, но здесь часто любые предположения заканчиваются вообще не тем , что хотел автор.

Comment: Ну то что код страны начинается с +, это международный формат и то что код города идет в (###) аналогично. По этому не думал что у кого то возникнут трудности с пониманием этого. На будущие буду знать ))

Comment: Это может быть и так понятно, но поскольку это и есть суть задачи, то именно этот текст и надо было озвучить в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение вида

```
foreach($data as $d){
    preg_match("/\+(?<plus>\d+)[-\s](\((?<brackets>\d+)\))?/", $d->mask, $matches);
    print_r([$d->mask, $matches]);
}
```

для номера `+93-##-###-####` вернет соответствие `$matches['plus']` равное `93`.

Для номера `+1 (268) ###-####` вернет

```
 plus => 1
 brackets => 268
```

В данном выражении:

1. `\+` начальный знак `+` с экранированием. Можете добавить начало строки `^\+`
2. `(?<plus>\d+)` именованная маска для первой группы цифр. Можете ограничить длину, заменив `+` на `{1-4}`
3. Далее следует дефис либо пробел `[-\s]`
4. Далее опциональная группа  `(...)?` внутри которой экранированные скобки `\(...\)` внутри которых именованная группа захвата `(?<brackets>\d+)`